# how to keep active onclick on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#2").click(function () {
         $("#content").load("{% url 'about' %}");
       });

    $("#3").click(function () {
      $("#content").load("{% url 'pay' %}");
    });

 });
```

========== html ===========

```
<a id="2" href="#">click me </a>
<a id="3" href="#">pay </a>

<div id="content"></div>

<h1>hello</h1>

{% endblock test %}
```

I am trying to archive that if i reload the page the html fill that called in div remain the same until i click another page link.

Comment: Best bet would be to use some cookie or something to store what link was clicked

Comment: Can u please suggest me some examples or link.

Comment: You could also use `window.history.pushState` (so that it updates the url) the popstate to to re-set the active link on page refresh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `localStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to keep limited state between page reloads. Keep in mind that `localStorage` will hold the same values even if you access it from another tab of the same browser with the same web site/domain. It will persist even between browser restarts.

Here is a simple test:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function documentLoaded()
    {
        var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
        function refresh()
        {
            contentDiv.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("content");
        }

        var link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
        var link2 = document.getElementById("link2");
        var link3 = document.getElementById("link3");
        
        link1.onclick = function(){localStorage.setItem("content", "div text 1"); refresh();}
        link2.onclick = function(){localStorage.setItem("content", "div text 2"); refresh();}
        link3.onclick = function(){localStorage.setItem("content", "div text 3"); refresh();}

        refresh();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:documentLoaded()">
    <a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)">link 1</a><br />
    <a id="link2" href="javascript:void(0)">link 2</a><br />
    <a id="link3" href="javascript:void(0)">link 3</a><br />
    
    <div id="content">default div text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to make it work with multiple user sessions in the same browser, you could append some unique user identifier to the local storage id, e.g. `localStorage.getItem("content" + currentUser.id);`